# C can't print a string twice

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am doing a project where i must create a Black Jack simulation. So i started by creating a deck and a draw function. Since there are no strings in C i created two arrays of pointers to use them as a custom-string arrays. The thing is that when i print the card to see its value and suit ,only the first time it prints what expected. The second time is a mess. Can someone explain this to me ? Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
char* suit[] = {"Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs"};
char* facevalue[] = { "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack","Queen", "King", "Ace"};
char* drawCard()
{
    char* card[50];
    int cardNumber=rand()%8;
    int cardColor=rand()%4;
    strcpy(card,facevalue[cardNumber]);
    char of[]=" of  ";
    char* xrwma =suit[cardColor];
    strncat(card,of,5);
    strncat(card,xrwma,8);
    return card;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char* c=drawCard();
    puts(c);
    puts(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are returning a pointer to an automatic array. Once the function returns, the array goes out of scope. Attempting to dereference the returned pointer results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The first call to `puts()`, while technically undefined, happens to work in your case. The second doesn't.

See [Returning a pointer to an automatic variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224042/returning-a-pointer-to-an-automatic-variable) for a discussion.

One solution is to allocate the array inside `main()`, pass a pointer to it (and its size) to `drawCard()` and let `drawCard()` populate it.

Comment: Also, which solution is preferred? Pass a pointer to `drawCard()` or use f.e `malloc` ? In order to have a cleaner code. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Variable `card` is a local array in function `drawCard`.

Being as such, it is allocated in the stack when function `drawCard` executes.

After function `drawCard` returns, you can no longer rely on the contents of this array.

Any succeeding operation may override that piece of memory at any time.

The fact that your program successfully prints it at the first call to `puts`, is nothing more than "a matter of luck" - the correct characters just happen to reside in the memory pointed by variable `c`, upon the first call to function `fputs`.

But since function `fputs` also uses the stack, that piece of memory is overridden soon thereafter, and by the time you call `fputs` again, the previous character values are no longer there.

BTW, looking at your usage of variable `card`, I get the feeling that you meant to declare it as `char card[50]` rather than `char* card[50]`.

Comment: +1 for the `char* card[50]`.  This implies the compiler's  warnings are not fully engaged.  Something OP should fix.

Comment: Is it ok if i just declare it as `char *card` ?

Comment: Well, `char* card = malloc(50*sizeof(char))` or `char card[50]`, whichever you prefer. Just keep in mind that if you choose the first option then you have to call `free(...)` at some later point, and if you choose the second option then you cannot use it outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking the problem is the lifetime of the automatic variable that `drawCard()` returns. It's only good for the one function call instance. C doesn't stop you from returning it but it's invariably not useful later.

And the reason for that is: the locals (*automatic* storage class) are allocated on the stack. It's *really* fast; a single arithmetic op -- a subtract from the stack pointer -- can allocate every local in a function.

But when the call returns, the stack is adjusted back. At this point the *next* function call instance is going to reuse the same space. If you hang on to a reference into that space it will get trashed with superficially random and ever-changing stuff ...