# C - Contents of char array changing unexpectedly

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, file-io

I have some code intended to be used in a much larger program, It gets user's input and then should write that input to a file, However the data is somehow lost just before/during writing to a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *input();
void output(char text[1000]);
int main()
{   
    char text[1000]={'\0'}, *textPtr;
    textPtr=text;   
    textPtr=input();
    output(textPtr);
}

char *input()
{
    char text[1000], *textPtr=text;
    textPtr=text;   
    fflush(stdin);//Clears the newline character left by any prevoius scanf statements
    scanf("%[^\n]s",textPtr);
    return textPtr;
}

void output(char text[1000])
{
    FILE *file;
    printf("\nText before file statement:\n");
    printf("%s\n",text);
    //For some reason this line seems to trigger a change in 'text'
    file=fopen("output.txt","a");
    printf("\nText after file statement:\n");
    printf("%s\n",text);    
    fprintf(file,"%s\n",text);
    fclose(file);       
    printf("\nText after write and close statement:\n");
    printf("%s\n",text);    
}
```

The print statements in the output function output something similar to this image no matter the input

[image]

So it prints the desired contents of 'text' directly before those contents are used in the intended way, it then replaces those contents with nothing, and writes just a line break to the text document and then in the next print statement the text becomes a single strange accented character (varies each time program is run).

So I believe somehow I have misused pointers or I am returning the char array from a function in a strange way.

Comment: You should also check the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a pointer to an automatic variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224042/returning-a-pointer-to-an-automatic-variable)

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior, it is not defined to work for input streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textPtr=input();` return a new pointer on the stack that is freed when the function `input` return and then this memory (stack) can be use again.
To fix this you have to pass `textPtr` as parameters of `input`

```
input(textPtr);//the call

input(char * textPtr){//the function
    fflush(stdin);//Clears the newline character left by any prevoius scanf statements
    scanf("%[^\n]s",textPtr);
}
```