# How to pass pointers as arguments where store an array address

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I do my best to expalin what I'm trying to develop:

1. I have developed a *function2* into a library which returns the address of an array.

   ```
   uint16_t * readArray(void)
   {
     uint16_t array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
     return array;
   }
   ```
2. Another *function1* from the same library has to store this address into a pointer that is passed as argument. This function does not return nothing, but the address need to be save in the pointer.

   ```
   void readAddress(uint16_t *pointer_)
   {
     pointer_ = readArray();
   }
   ```
3. From '*main*' function, values from the array need to be printed.

   ```
   uint16_t *values;

   int main(void)
   {
     ...
     readAddres(values);
     print(values);      // This function prints the complete array
     ...
   }
   ```

   - Function declarations are omitted conciously (*library.h*).

What I have found is doing so, the value stored in 'pointer_' is not the array's address.

This is a pointer issue, and I would be pleased if someone could help me to understand how to develop a situation like this.

KR!

Comment: Read about passing by value, passing arrays to a function, and modifying pointers. This'll solve your problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a pointer to an automatic variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224042/returning-a-pointer-to-an-automatic-variable)

Comment: This is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate .....

Comment: regarding this line: `uint16_t array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`.  this array is on the stack of the enclosing function and disappears when the function exits.  one easy way to correct that is: `static uint16_t array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Comment: regarding this line: `readAddres(values);`.  In C, items are always passed by value,  to change where a pointer points in a calling function, the address of that pointer must be passed.  So the line should be: `readAddres( &values );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What I have found is doing so, the value stored in 'pointer_' is not the array's address.**

This is because `uint16_t array[5]` is local to the function `readArray`, and it gets destroyed when the function returns.

---

To make this work you can allocate memory in heap. Memory allocated in heap is retained in between function calls.

Use the [`malloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) system call to allocate memory in heap.

Comment: There is no need to involve `malloc` here. Check @machine_1's Answer.

Comment: @Michi, It cannot be done just by changing the `readAddress` function. He also has mentioned that. *... Try this after fixing `readArray()`*.

Answer (score 3):

Since `array[5]` is a local variable,it gets wiped out when the function terminates.

As for your function `void readAddress(uint16_t *pointer_)`,it cannot change the value of the supplied pointer since it is passed by Value.you need to change it to accept `uint16_t**` as an argument.Try this after fixing `readArray()`:

```
void readAddress(uint16_t **pointer_)
{
    *pointer_ = readArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uint16_t * readArray(void)
{
  uint16_t array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  return array;
}
```

The array is initialized only when this function is called and its heap is destroyed as soon as the function returns.

```
  pointer_ = readArray();
```

So, will always have point to null.
I had the same issue once and a colleague of mine suggested an elegant solution, which, for your case would be:

```
void readArray(uint16_t *ptr)
{
  uint16_t array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      ptr[i]=array[i];
}

void readAddress(uint16_t *pointer_)
{
  readArray(pointer_);
}
```

In this case you, if you desire, you may even get rid of readAddress method and from you main call

```
readArray(values);
```