# Understanding pointer behavior in structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I define a structure with a single field and an init function like so:

```
typedef struct{
  int* field;
}myStruct;
myStruct init(int x){
  myStruct s;
  s.field = &x;
  return s;
}
```

I then declare two of these structure and then print the field of the first.

```
int main(){
  myStruct s1 = init(1);
  myStruct s2 = init(2);
  printf("s1.field=%d\n",*s1.field);
  return 0;
}
```

The result of this is "s1.field=2". Why does the initialization of the second affect the first?

Comment: undefined behaviour: `int x` is a parameter, like a local variable, you cannot take the reference and expect it to keep the data. It's auto memory, so it's reused when init exits.

Comment: You are storing the address of a local variable. It's life time ends when the init function returns. Thus you are invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: you get the previous value because you're calling the same function. Call another function (with another set of parameters/stack frame) and you'll get garbage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a pointer to an automatic variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224042/returning-a-pointer-to-an-automatic-variable)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: There is no guarantee which value is returned. It's undefined behaviour (see the dupe), so anything can happen, just wait for nasal daemons.

Comment: agreed, it's UB, in that case "you get the previous value because you're calling the same function" and the compiler uses the same stackframe. But that's just the explanation. The fact that it returns a "valid" value and not just garbage probably confused OP even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling this function twice:

```
myStruct init(int x){
  myStruct s;
  s.field = &x;
  return s;
}
```

On both calls, the variable (or parameter) `x` is allocated, but not valid anymore when the function returns. You've stored the address of a local variable, and since you're using the same function, the local variable address is the same the second time, which explains the "magic" (which is still *undefined behaviour* but most compilers using stack for auto variables will yield the same result)

Unfortunately compilers aren't smart enough to detect that you're storing an address of a local variables. They usually trigger warnings when you're *returning* an address on a local (it's easier to detect).

For instance if you call `printf`, you will get not 1 or 2 but complete garbage as the parameter memory won't be organized the same way as your function.

A clean way would be to allocate dynamic memory:

```
s.field = malloc(sizeof(*s.field));  // this memory persists even after the end of "init"
*s.field = x;  // copying the value, not the address
```

Of course it needs deallocation when structure isn't used.

Comment: The question is just another variant of the well know dupe. VtC.

Comment: except that it's not _returning_ the pointer (which triggers a compiler warning), but _storing_ it.

Comment: It returns a `struct` with the pointer. That's no relevant difference.

Comment: the main difference is the lack of warning, the compiler isn't smart enough to see that you're storing the variable, as opposed to when you _return_ it.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact it's a dupe. There is no requirement for the compiler to warn. Consider the following: `auto int a= 40, *p = &a, *q = p; return q;` I doubt the compiler will warn about this either (if it does, add another ring to the chain). Would you consider this also not a dupe? How about another ring? All seperate questions? It's better to understand the underlying problem, which is the general problem of the users asking such questions and **trying** to learn C from YT.

Comment: well, unlike for your music recommendations, I respectfully disagree. That was your right to vote to close. You know I like using the dupehammer when I agree.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite dupe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733664/explain-the-output-and-why-does-y-not-point-to-garbage-value :)

Answer (score 1):

Any variable has some space in the memory. A pointer references that space. The space that local variables occupies is deallocated when the function call returns, meaning that it can and will be reused for other things. As a consequence, references to that space are going to wind up pointing to something completely unrelated.

The preferable way would be to use malloc() to reserve non-local memory. the danger here is that you have to deallocate (free()) everything you allocated using malloc(), and if you forget, you create a memory leak.

Comment: "Any variable has some space in the memory. A pointer references that space." --> Aside from those pesky "register" ones.

Comment: "Any variable has some space in the memory." - This is not guaranteed by the standard. There is not even a guarantee to use a register, as C does not really know about CPU registers, A modern compiler will possibly completely eliminate a variable out of existence for example.

Answer (score 1):

In the function

```
myStruct init(int x){
  myStruct s;
  s.field = &x;
  return s;
}
```

you are assigning the address of `x` to `s.field`.  The problem is that `x` is local to the function, and once the function exits, *ceases to exist* (logically speaking - obviously, the memory location it occupied is still there, but it's now available for something else to use and may be overwritten).  That pointer value is now *invalid*, and attempting to dereference it leads to undefined behavior.

What's most likely happening *in this particular case* is that the space that was used for `x` in the `init(1)` call is being reused and overwritten in the `init(2)` call, and miraculously that location is either not being overwritten by the `printf` call, or `printf` is writing a `2` to that location as part of its operations.